# How to upload User using Excel File

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-5

i am trying to upload user from one sql database to other sql database using excel file but i am not able to upload user in the identityuser table of the Application.

here is my code please correct me if i am wrong anywhere

```
                        SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection();
                        sqlc.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Planetskool-20150303080110.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Planetskool-20150303080110;Integrated Security=True";
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IdentityUser (Id,UserName,Email,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,Discriminator)  VALUES(@Id,@UserName,@Email,@PasswordHash,@SecurityStamp,@Discriminator)", sqlc);//@OB_ID is indentity primary key
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Id"]);
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["UserName"]).ToString();
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Email"]).ToString();
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@PasswordHash", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["PasswordHash"]).ToString();
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@SecurityStamp", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["SecurityStamp"]).ToString();
                        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Discriminator", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "ApplicationUser";
                        sqlc.Open();
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlc.Close();
```

When i am debugging the database it showing the id == null so there is any solution to this problem

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what `ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["Id"]` returns exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül yes exactly i check it using debug ..its coming null .. and excel which i am downloading may be problem  i will show the screenshot

Comment: @SonerGönül This is Screenshot of Excel
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B25kMEExemspSHB2dDVHV195Tjg

Comment: The code you've shown us populates data into a SQL database.  There would probably be more code you're not showing us that reads the data from your spreadsheet, and we can't solve without that.  Also, making a new database connection object for each row of the spreadsheet is a bad idea.